# withTimeout function gives IllegalStateException: There is no event loop. Use runBlocking { ... } to start one. in Kotlin Multiplatform iOS client

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, ktor, kotlin-native

Update:
It works if I first execute a coroutine without timeout and then withTimeout. But If I execute a coroutine withTimeout first then it gives me an error. same goes for Async as well.

I am creating a demo kotlin multiplatform application where I am executing an API call with ktor.
I want to have a configurable timeout function on ktor request so I am using withTimeout at coroutine level.

Here is my function call with network API.

```
suspend fun <T> onNetworkWithTimeOut(
    url: String,
    timeoutInMillis: Long,
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Any): T {
    return withTimeout(timeoutInMillis) {
        withContext(dispatchers.io, block)
    } as T
}

suspend fun <T> onNetworkWithoutTimeOut(url: String, block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Any): T {
    return withContext(dispatchers.io, block) as T
}
```

Here is my AppDispatcher class for the iOSMain module.

```
@InternalCoroutinesApi
actual class AppDispatchersImpl : AppDispatchers {
@SharedImmutable
override val main: CoroutineDispatcher =
    NsQueueDispatcher(dispatch_get_main_queue())

@SharedImmutable
override val io: CoroutineDispatcher =
    NsQueueDispatcher(dispatch_get_main_queue())

internal class NsQueueDispatcher(
    @SharedImmutable private val dispatchQueue: dispatch_queue_t
) : CoroutineDispatcher() {
    override fun dispatch(context: CoroutineContext, block: Runnable) {
        NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().performBlock {
            block.run()
        }
    }
}
```

}

so the function with the timeout gives me the following error in iOS client.

```
kotlin.IllegalStateException: There is no event loop. Use runBlocking { ... } to start one.
```

I am using 1.3.2-native-mt-1 version of the kotlin-coroutine-native.
I have created a sample demo application at the following URL.
https://github.com/dudhatparesh/kotlin-multiplat-platform-example

Comment: The error is only coming in iOS client? Android client works properly?

Comment: Yes Android client is working perfectly fine

Comment: Am running in to similar issue when trying to update https://github.com/joreilly/PeopleInSpace to use native mt version of coroutines....trying `1.3.3-native-mt` version mentioned in https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/462.  Seems we should be using `newSingleThreadContext` but that doesn't resolve for some reason.

Answer (score 9):

So, as mentioned in comment above I had similar issue but turned out that it wasn't picking up the `native-mt` version due to transitive dependencies in other libraries.  Added following and it's resolving now.

```
        implementation('org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native') 
        {
            version {
                strictly '1.3.3-native-mt'
            }
        }
```

Also note guidance in https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/native-mt/kotlin-native-sharing.md

Starting to make use of this in https://github.com/joreilly/PeopleInSpace

Comment: Just tried that. didn't work getting the same error.

Comment: I have added your fix on the repository at
https://github.com/dudhatparesh/kotlin-multiplat-platform-example

Comment: Thanks to John's answer I was able to call the below function successfully from iOS

```
@InternalCoroutinesApi
fun backgroundTest() {
  val job = GlobalScope.launch {
    kprint("we are on main thread \n")
    withContext(Dispatchers.Default) {
      kprint("hello \n")
      delay(2000)
      kprint("world \n")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey John. Thanks for this. Any idea how I can get ktor to build then? Any way I can force it to use `1.3.3-native-mt`? I get `Could not resolve org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core-native:1.3.3.
     Required by:
         project :shared > io.ktor:ktor-client-ios:1.3.0 > io.ktor:ktor-client-ios-iosx64:1.3.0`

Comment: @CarsonHolzheimer I'd recommend looking at dependency setup in https://github.com/joreilly/PeopleInSpace

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly Thanks again. I resolved it by upgrading my gradle version to 6 like you had in the example.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `[withTimeout]` functions in coroutines you have to modify your `Dispatcher` to implement [`Delay`](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/kotlinx-coroutines-core/common/src/Delay.kt) interface. Here is an example of how this can be achieved:

```
@UseExperimental(InternalCoroutinesApi::class)
class UI : CoroutineDispatcher(), Delay {

    override fun dispatch(context: CoroutineContext, block: Runnable) {
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            try {
                block.run()
            } catch (err: Throwable) {
                throw err
            }
        }
    }

    @InternalCoroutinesApi
    override fun scheduleResumeAfterDelay(timeMillis: Long, continuation: CancellableContinuation<Unit>) {
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, timeMillis * 1_000_000), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            try {
                with(continuation) {
                    resumeUndispatched(Unit)
                }
            } catch (err: Throwable) {
                throw err
            }
        }
    }

    @InternalCoroutinesApi
    override fun invokeOnTimeout(timeMillis: Long, block: Runnable): DisposableHandle {
        val handle = object : DisposableHandle {
             var disposed = false
                private set

            override fun dispose() {
                disposed = true
            }
        }
        dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, timeMillis * 1_000_000), dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            try {
                if (!handle.disposed) {
                    block.run()
                }
            } catch (err: Throwable) {
                throw err
            }
        }

        return handle
    }

}
```

This solution can be easily modified for your needs.

More information can be found in [this thread](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/470).

**UPDATE**

At the moment there is a version `1.3.9-native-mt` of `kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core` artifact which gives the ability to use `Dispatchers.Main` on ios platform (it supports `delay` out of the box). It even supports `Dispatchers.Default` which is used for background work. You can read [docs](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/native-mt) in native-mt branch. Worth noting that the version for ios should be set strictly:

```
implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.3.9-native-mt") {
            version {
                strictly('1.3.9-native-mt')
            }
        }
```

Comment: I tried that solution as well. still, it's giving the same error. however, if I execute any coroutine which does not have timeout before executing the coroutine with timeout it works just fine.

Comment: @PareshDudhat The behaviour you've mentioned is rather strange. There is [`Dispatchers.Unconfined`](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-dispatchers/-unconfined.html) dispatcher, which have the [mechanism](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/coroutines/coroutine-context-and-dispatchers.html#unconfined-vs-confined-dispatcher) rather similar to what you are describing. Are you fully sure about the way you launch your coroutine?

Comment: I am launching it with  launch(dispatchers.main), I have also tried launching it with 
dispatcher.main + job but no help. I pushed the latest commit on the GitHub repo

Comment: Beautiful, all i wanted was to call delay in a suspend function and this solution worked like a charm! Thanks @art

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes ios app has a different async requirement with an android app.
Use this code for temporary dispatch problem

```
object MainLoopDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher() {
    override fun dispatch(context: CoroutineContext, block: Runnable) {
        NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().performBlock {
            block.run()
        }
    }
}
```

Please see the forum for this issue: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/issues/470